# While loop running forever

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am creating a basic while loop and for some reason it runs infinitely. I want to understand what it is not stopping at the length of var "days".

```
var day1 = 1
var days = 365

while (day1 <= days) {
    day1++;
 if (day1 = 358) {
    console.log('today is christmas');
 } else {
    console.log("today is day " + day1);
 }
}
```

Comment: Tip for your next question http://jshint.com

Comment: `if (day1 = 358)` Why are you assigning 358 to day1?

Comment: I bet looking in the console would have tipped you off that every day is Christmas.

Comment: @jstone Did you get a closure on this? :)

Answer (score 9):

Reason is because you are doing an assignment (=) instead of comparison (===) and the value of variable `day1` remains as 358 forever. Also you might have noted it logging "today is christmas" always because of the assignment and the result is a nonzero value which makes it truthy always.

Change

```
if (day1 = 358) {
```

to

```
if (day1 === 358) {
```

Just to add on you could also use `==` as well which does a type coercion (Which is not required in your case) as well during comparison but `===` is a strict equality comparison and which is recommended in most cases.

Comment: Cool thank you, I knew it was something super simple :) n merry Christmas!

Comment: @jstone You are welcome.. and merry christmas to you too... :)

Comment: @PSL - you should have also mentioned the difference between `==` and `===`.

Answer (score 6):

When you say

```
if (day1 = 358) {
```

You are not comparing the values, but you are assigning `358` to `day1` in every iteration. So, the value never changes. Thats why it runs into an infinite loop. To fix this,

Use comparison operator like this

```
if (day1 === 358) {
```